# How to change The PublishingWebAgent FileDeploymentServer port channge in LINUX

Tags: server, configuration, atg, atg-dynamo, atg-droplet

I tried to change the FileDeploymentServer port in my ATG linux system but it take default port 8810 how To change this

```
**** Error  Wed May 13 08:22:57 EDT 2020    1589372577963   /atg/deployment/file/FileDeploymentServer   Service /atg/deployment/file/FileDeploymentServer found port 8810 is already in use.  Either another instance of this server is running or you need to set the port in <config-dir>/atg/deployment/file/FileDeploymentServer.properties
```

Install Location : /home/WorkHome/ATG/ATGWeb11.3.2

I search this file but not Find /atg/deployment/file/FileDeploymentServer this location

I Need to change the port from 8810 to 9000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am Just creating the FileDeploymentServer.properties in this location /atg/deployment/file the add single line in that  file FileDeploymentServer.properties

```
port=9000
```

Now Its change NO error

Answer (score 0):

In your localconfig folder you need to modify the `/atg/dynamo/Configuration.properties` file.

Update the `fileDeploymentPort` and set it to your preferred setting.

You will need to restart the instance.